# locate type in struts-config.xml

Tags: java, struts

here is my `struts-config.xml`

```
<action input="/jsp/admin/DocumentDetail.jsp" name="documentDetailForm" parameter="pageAction" path="/documentDetails" scope="request" type="com.company.product.web.admin.DocumentDetailsAction" validate="false">
      <set-property property="moduleCode" value="documentsAdmin"/>
      <forward name="saveDocDetails" path="/documentSave.do?pageAction=save"/>
      <forward name="openAddTagPage" path="/jsp/admin/DocumentTagList.jsp"/>
      <forward name="cancel" path="/documentList.do?pageAction=search"/>
      <forward name="success" path="/documentList.do?pageAction=search"/>
    </action>
```

Because this help generates the `DocumentDetails.jsp`, i am interested in editing the original file that help create the jsp. My guess is that the java file is `com.company.product.web.admin.DocumentDetailsAction` but i have trouble finding it in my workspace in Eclipse.

The `DocumentDetails.jsp` is

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>

<tr>
<td width="25%" class="label">&nbsp;&nbsp;<bean:message key="documentReqSign" /></td>
        <td>
            <html:checkbox property="requiredSign" /> 
                </td>
</tr>
```

Btw, this is my first time using Struts, thanks!

Comment: Try to keep the CTRL key pressed and click on DocumentDetailsAction in the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for : `company/product/web/admin/documentDetailsAction.java`
in your project

So as you stated the file in question that is the right action, usually in struts all actions classes are grouped under one directory, you could try and use @pradeepsimha shortcuts or you could `ctrl+h` to search workspace for `DocumentDetails` then select the file in question.

Comment: yeah, i tried looking for `DocumentDetails.java` and `documentDetailsAction.java` and i can't find it..but at least its reassuring to know I'm on the right track

Comment: @bouncingHippo, if you can't find how does code even compile? is your code compiling successfully?

Comment: maybe you are looking under the wrong path or maybe you have only the compiled classes and not the source code of the actions.

Comment: i realize i have to download my sources through maven as they are compiled but appear as a `jar` file in my workspace.

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse to develop and I rely on ECL downloader for this but I suppose it's possible to import the jar file as source otherwise just extract it with winrar and add the src folder to your project

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + R -> DocumentDetailsAction or Ctrl + Shift + O -> com.company.product.web.admin.DocumentDetailsAction doesn't work??